# Upload medium or larg file size in host (images,multimedia files,...) without ftp protocol

Tags: file-upload, vb6, host, msxml

How can **make a uploader file in vb6** to work easyly and can be uploade files into host.

For example (images or multimedia files or other format) and size > small size files  for exampe > 500kb or 1 mb , 2 mb or upper sizes .

Please help me to can find any way to designed  **without ftp protocols**.

I think it is possible to use of msxml refrences but i don't know how can designed it by msxml .

[thanks]

Comment: It is not necessary to use tags in your tile. You can refer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles for guidance.

Comment: any body not here can help ?!!! i need vb6 uploader larg size file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could upload to a HTTP like dropbox. The downside of simple HTTP file transfer is that it is fairly easy for somebody to grab your credentials using a common tool like Fiddler. However that is also the case with FTP just a bit harder. The upside to uploading to dropbox is that you could have any file size (providing you have the space on your dropbox account).

I haven't tried using the dropbox upload api yet but you can read the documentation here, take a look at the PUT and POST methods: https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs

If you just wanted to upload to dropbox and you have the dropbox client installed you could just save the file to the dropbox folder on your computer and it would auto upload.

Comment: my means of larg file is vb6 source code to can uploade larg file size to my host.my means was not large space services provider - i want make a program with vb6 to can uploade for example 5 mb on my host.

Comment: i finded many source to uploade file with vb6 but sources worked with small size file or worked with ftp protocol.any body here can help me to find diffrent source ?

Comment: _i am waiting yet ..._